# Create elements only once inside for loop and assign id to it from an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array  majorArray, suppose it contains `20, 25, 30, 35`. When I put it inside a loop and create elements dynamically as coded below, this element is created multiple times as the length of an array. However, I only want to create only one for each value and assign `id` by value of a specific position of an array to the `li` tag.

Please help to solve my problem?

```
for(i = 0; i <= majorArray.length; i++) {
    var ul_client_listing = ('.clientlisting').addClass('client_ul').append('<ul>');
    var li_client_listing = $('.client_ul ul').addClass('client_li').append('<li id="first'+majorArray[i]+'" class="mainli"> <div class="cientname"> </div></li>');
    $('.cientname').append('<input type="text" placeholder="comment..." class="reviewtext1" style="margin-top:10px"/>');
}
```

Comment: you may need to clarify more

Comment: Also what is the significance of the array, don't water down the problem for SO, we can handle it.

Comment: majorArray is an array containing value 20,25,30,35, I have to assign it to element li as id, but the problem is that my element get created multiple times because it is in a loop and it will be printed till majorArray.length. Please suggest any solutions.

Comment: So you wan to have 4 `ul` each one with one `li` and some elements inside that `li`? or you want to add 4 li to one ul, little confusing what the desired output is.

Comment: Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net. We can't see the overall problem well with just what is shown and description is not very clear either. An example of the existing html structure added to question would help

Comment: Have you looked at the `lodash` library?

Comment: Could you show your starting HTML and the desired finishing HTML and, ideally, more clearly explain what it is that you want to do. If English isn't your first language it might be worth asking a friend or colleague, with more experience, to help you phrase your question. It *seems* valid, and is probably worthwhile, but it's hard to help when we can't understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the way you're creating and adding new elements is you use selectors which not only selects the newly created elements, but all such elements.

For example inside your loop you have:

```
var ul_client_listing = ('.clientlisting').addClass('client_ul').append('<ul>');
```

And then right after that you append a `li` to `$('.client_ul ul')` which is not only the newly created `ul`, but all the `ul` with an ancestor with class `.client_ul`. And the same about `li` elements.

You can do it like this:

```
var container = $('.clientlisting').addClass('client_ul');
for (i = 0; i <= majorArray.length; i++) {
    var ul = $('<ul/>');
    var li = $('<li/>').prop('id', 'first' + majorArray[i]).addClass('mainli');
    var div = $('<div/>').addClass('cientname');
    var inp = $('<input/>').attr({
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'comment...',
                class: 'reviewtext1'
            }).css('margin-top', '10px');
    div.append(inp);
    li.append(div);
    ul.append(li);
    container.append(ul);
}
```